# Appending and exporting data to .dat files with corresponding timestamp

Tags: r, header, dataframe, export, append

I am new to R. I was using basic functions in fortran90 but have made the step to R. I am trying to do calculations on a time series, first I am doing very basic calculations on the input parameters by reading in my data e.g.:

```
data <- read.table("mydata.dat",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
```

which for example looks like this:

```
datetime            Ttop    Tbot
11/07/2013 19:16    20.61   20.5
11/07/2013 19:17    20.62   20.49
11/07/2013 19:18    20.6    20.48
11/07/2013 19:19    20.6    20.47
```

Then I find the average temp at both top and bottom as Tav:

```
Tav <- data.frame((data$Ttop+data$Tbot)/2)
```

Then the saturation pressure of water as Vav using:

```
Vav <- data.frame((0.0000802*Tav^3)-(0.000717*Tav^2)+(0.0717*Tav)+0.539)
```

How then can I export this data with a specified header e.g. "Tav" and "Vav", respectively and append it to the original .dat file so that also have a corresponding date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have now created two new data.frames. I think it would have been more practical to add the new variables to the existing data.frame:

```
data$Tav <- data$Ttop+data$Tbot)/2
data$Vav <- (0.0000802*Tav^3)-(0.000717*Tav^2)+(0.0717*Tav)+0.539
```

This data.frame can then be saved using `write.table`:

```
write.table(data, file="mynewdata.dat", row.names=FALSE, sep="\t", quote=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Tav <- with(data, (Ttop + Tbot)/2)
transform(data, Tav = Tav, Vav = (0.0000802*Tav^3)-(0.000717*Tav^2)+(0.0717*Tav)+0.539)
```

or using `my.transform` found [here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/07/09/24707.html) try this:

```
my.transform(data, 
         Tav = (Ttop + Tbot)/2),
         Vav = (0.0000802*Tav^3)-(0.000717*Tav^2)+(0.0717*Tav)+0.539)
)
```